# prove its a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A=$\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 0&-1\\ 1&0\end {array}
 \right] $

$L:Mat_2\mathbb{R}\rightarrow Mat_2\mathbb{R}$

$B\rightarrow AB-BA$

(1) Show that it is a linear transformation.

I really have no idea how to this, expect I know that:

$L(u+w)=L(u)+L(w)$

$\alpha*L(v)=L(\alpha*V)$

Can anyone help me prove this?

Answer (score 2):

Let $B,C \in Mat_2\Bbb R$, $\alpha,\beta \in\Bbb R$.

$\begin{align}L(\alpha B + \beta C)& = A(\alpha B + \beta C)-(\alpha B + \beta C)A\\
& = \alpha AB + \beta AC - \alpha BA - \beta CA \\
& = (\alpha AB-\alpha BA) + (\beta AC - \beta CA) \\
& = \alpha(AB-BA) + \beta (AC-CA) \\
& = \alpha L(B) + \beta L(C)
\end{align}$

This proves linearity.

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$
L(B) = AB - BA
$$
Example: Then for any $B \in \text{Mat}_2\mathbb{R}$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we have:
$$
L(\alpha B) 
= A(\alpha B) - (\alpha B) A
= \alpha AB - \alpha BA
= \alpha(AB - BA)
= \alpha L(B)
$$

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient to prove linearity, you are missing the preservetion of addition

Comment: I left that for the OP.

Comment: Ups, sorry then

Answer (score 0):

The replies by Giulio and mvw are, of course, exactly correct! But, as a teacher, I believe that giving a formal answer to this question can sometimes make a simple concept seem complicated.

Here's a lesson where I try to explain linearity simply: http://lem.ma/Yz
I think that if you understand how simple linearity is, you will be able to do the formal proof with great ease. Otherwise, the proof will continue to look like an a vexing stream of characters. (I've certainly been there.)

If you understand linearity, you will see $AB-BA$ as **obviously** linear in $B$. Maybe it'll help to see examples that are not linear in $B$:
$$AB^2-B^2A$$
$$AB-BA+I$$
$$AB^{-1}-BA$$
$$A(B+I)-(B+I)A$$

Let me know if this, combined with the video, helps and, if not, we'll try to clarify the issue!

Comment: Such a simple example really gives, a great intuition of what it is. If you are the one doing these videos, you should definitely continue. I surely had a "aha! moment". Thank you very much!